# Django for pros: How to query time slots by start time and duration? F() expression?

Tags: django, postgresql

## The problem

How do I query for the time slots in DB that intersect with a specific 5pm-7pm slot which is my query?

The logic starts like that:

```
Q(start_time__lt=start_hour) &
Q(duration__gt=comparison_python_function(F('start_time'), query_start_time)
```

As far as I understand I can do simple operations such as `F('column_name') + 1`. However, in my case I need a python formula to calculate the relationship between a `TimeField` and `DecimalField`. From what I get, this is not possible.

How do I deal then with querying timeslots given that the two columns can not be compared directly but are dependent on each other? Or if this can't be done, how else would I do it? Am I missing a different approach?

## A bit of history:

I need to store in the database time slots. I tried with `start_time` and `end_time`.

The problem with this approach is that after midnight `end_time` becomes smaller than `start_time` and this messes up everything.

It made a lot more sense to go with the approach `start_time` and `duration`. Start time is type `models.TimeField()` while duration is `models.DecimalField()`.

The big problem here is querying the database as explained.
Using Django 1.7 with Postgres

Comment: Django 1.8 (LTS version) introduces a [`DurationField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#durationfield), and is about to be released (this Wednesday, probably). If upgrading is an option for you, I'd suggest using that. It uses PostgreSQL's native `interval` data type. I believe there are third-party apps implementing the same for 1.7. Otherwise, it would require a bit of custom SQL.

Comment: Even if sub-ideal, 1.8c1 does work with mixing postgres `timestamp` and `interval` through `DurationField`, for which I thank you. I would have loved to see a simpler solution than upgrading though.